# Dapptools Fork Impersonation?

Tags: signature, local-variables, dapptools, seth

In hardhat, theres a way to 'impersonateSigner' and fake a signature from an address you dont own on a forked mainnet; is there a way to do the same with seth? Naively setting the sender doesnt let me do that -- my local chain is still a hardhat one though.